# Translating words from one language to another

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, promise

My program translates words from one language to another using a language Pivot and [systran.io](http://www.systran.io/) API.

I used promises, callbacks and external API for the first time but I'm not sure that's the best way to use them. The function `Translate` will translate word and send a response via a callback. Then in the POST request, I used promises to chain tasks.

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');

var router = express.Router();

router.post("/", function(req, res) {
    console.log
    var resultat
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        translate(req.query.source, "en", req.query.content, function(resa) {
            resolve(resa);

        })
    }).then(function(resolve) {
        console.log(resolve);
        translate("en", req.query.target, resolve, function(resa2) {
            console.log(resa2);

        })
    });
});

function translate(source, target, content, callback) {
    let result;
    result = request("https://api-platform.systran.net/translation/text/translate?input=" + content + "&source=" + source + "&target=" + target + "&key=xxxxxxxx-783f-4f90-aea4-7fb357016647", function(err, data, body) {
        body = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(body);

        callback(body.outputs[0].output)
    })
}
module.exports = router;
```

Is there a better way to write my program, which is already working?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would have the `translate` call return a `Promise` rather than a callback and make use of `async`/`await` (presuming the version of Node you are using Node 6+) e.g.

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');

var router = express.Router();

router.post("/", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const translated = await translate(req.query.source, 'en', req.query.content);
    const result = await translate('en', req.query.target, translated); 
    // presume you intend on returning something from your API?
    return res.json({ result });
  } catch (e) {
    return next(e);
  }
})

const translate = (source, target, content) => 
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
    request(`https://api-platform.systran.net/translation/text/translate?input=${content}&source=${source}&target=${target}&key=xxxxxxxx-783f-4f90-aea4-7fb357016647`, (err, data, body) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);

      try {
        return resolve(JSON.parse(body));
      } catch (e) {
        return reject(e);
      }
    })
  );

module.exports = router;
```